# Fetch Pagination URL Data with NSURLConnection in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, pagination, nsurlconnection

i am newbie in iOS make an app that contain JSON Parsing data for that i use `NSURLConnection` and fetch data but here my URL Contain Pagination so, i want to fetch pagination data when tableView scroll for that i write a code like as

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
page=0;
NSString *path = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://isp.ebizzprojects.com/webservices/testimonial.php?page=%d",page];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:path]];
[NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:request delegate:self];
}
```

And Also I send second request when my table view scroll like as

```
- (void)scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
 {
NSInteger currentOffset = scrollView.contentOffset.y;
NSInteger maximumOffset = scrollView.contentSize.height- scrollView.frame.size.height;
if (maximumOffset - currentOffset <= 0)
{
    page = page + 1;
    [self getData];
}
}
 -(void)getData
 {
NSString *path = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://isp.ebizzprojects.com/webservices/testimonial.php?page=%d",page];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:path]];
[NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:request delegate:self];
 }
```

And NSURLConnection delegate method like as

```
-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response
 {
[_parsedData setLength:0];
 }
 -(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
{
[_parsedData appendData:data];
}
-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
{
_parsedData = nil;
_parsedData = [[NSMutableData alloc]init];
[[[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Alert!" message:@"Connection Error" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:@"Ok", nil]show];
 }
-(void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
 {
NSString *responseString =[[NSString alloc]initWithData:_parsedData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSDictionary *loDict = [responseString JSONValue];
self.responceArray=[loDict valueForKey:@"description"];
self.nameArray=[loDict valueForKey:@"name"];
self.testimonialTable.hidden=FALSE;
[self.testimonialTable reloadData];
}
```

From this my code when i scroll table view then i got only second page data i want to keep both data in to my table view when my tableview scroll please give me solution for this.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add new items to array like, create NSMutableArray for `self.responceArray` and `self.nameArray`

```
[self.responceArray addObjectsFromArray:[loDict valueForKey:@"description"]];
[self.nameArray addObjectsFromArray:[loDict valueForKey:@"name"]];
```